# Unchecking an angular bound checkbox programmatically

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to uncheck a checkbox bound using ng-model to a scope variable. Basically the below doesn't uncheck after 2 seconds.

html

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
</div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);   

function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.checked = true;

    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.checked = false;
        alert('should be unchecked!');
    },2000);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/tcVhN/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use angular **[$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)** service instead of javascript's **setTimeout**

Becuase if you use **setTimeout** in `angularjs` you need use `$scope.$apply()` to ensure the changes in scope. check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/tcVhN/189/)**

But **[$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)** will do this work for you.

Like this

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.checked = false;
    alert('should be unchecked!');
},2000);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/tcVhN/188/)**

Answer (score 1):

This work fine for me!

HTML FILE

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked" [checked]="checked" (change)="onChange(checked? 'block':'none')">
```

.TS FILE

```
export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {

  checked: boolean;

  constructor(public dados: DadosService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.dados.meusChamados == 'block')
    this.checked = true;
    else
    this.checked = false;
  }


  onChange(event : any){
    this.dados.meusChamados = event;
  }



}
```

checked = variable created on .ts file

onChange = a function created on .ts file to change the status of a div to display: none|block

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your checked variable to the selected attribute.

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" selected="{{checked}}">
</div>
```